# Powerquery to SQL using Cell value as parameter very slow

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery

**scenario:**

---

Running an XL sheet, using a single powerquery to retrieve data from a SQL server. The resulting dataset gets used in two subqueries. All three datasets are then loaded to pivot tables in the XL sheet.

**objective:**

---

Send query using 2 parameters retrieved from XL sheet, thereby reducing size of returned dataset. Folding query back onto SQL server, rather than filter post-retrieval in PQ.

**description of problem:**

---

if I use the below configuration for the main query:

```
let
    dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.somequery",
    Source = Sql.Database("<server>", "<database>", [Query=dbQuery])
in
    Source
```

This works fine and returns about 6500 rows almost instantly.

The following function is defined as 'GetRange' in PQ to retrieve a cell value:

```
(rangeName) => 
    Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=rangeName]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

Two parameters get retrieved by using below syntax for each:

```
= GetRange("<named cell>")
```

If I now change the dbQuery to:

```
dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.xlPAS_PivotOutput 
           WHERE parameter1=" & Text.From(parameter1) & " and parameter2=" & Text.From(parameter2),
```

The query does compile, and results are returned, but Excel PQ takes about 1 to 2 minutes to actually return a value? 
It appears that simply retrieving the 2 cell values and using them as input parameters takes a huge effort for some reason ?

Comment: Do you see the same slowdown if you put the parameters directly into your query? If you ignore privacy levels for your document (from Options | Current Workbook | Privacy), does the query speed up?

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT, Many thanks for your reply. If I put the values directly in query no problem, quick response. Only when values get read from the sheet there is a problem. Privacy settings are set to ignore, no difference there...

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to debug a query that was pulling in data from a URL that I pick up from a cell in the spreadsheet. It was running ridiculously slowly, whereas using the URL explicitly in the query was running fine. I kept trying to simplify the spreadsheet to troubleshoot up to the point I had a query that was just selecting the text value from a single cell in an otherwise empty spreadsheet and this was still slow as hell.

The Name Manager revealed that there were a couple of invalid name references and one referencing a range in another Excel file on another location which I couldn't access. Deleting these obsolete names seem to have fixed the problem.

The fact that name references that are unused in the spreadsheet cause this type of problem is definitely an Excel bug, but at least knowing this, searching for invalid name references and deleting them seems to fix the problem.